# Good overview of singularity theory

Tags: manifolds, ag.algebraic-geometry

Can anyone recommend a good overview of singularity theory? In particular, quotient singularities...

Comment: Could you provide a little more context?    I think your question is too broad to have a useful criterion for an answer.   Morse theory can be considered singularity theory, for example, but it's not clear if you want to allow that general a context.  

Comment: Stratified Morse Theory is more useful than Morse Theory for the study of singularities via differential topology. Such applications to algebraic geometry are discussed in the canonical reference, which is a book/monograph called Stratified Morse Theory. (I'm making this a comment because, among other things, I don't know any stratified Morse theory.)

Answer (score 9):

A book I found very helpful was the book by **János Kollár**, named **Lectures on Resolution of Singularities**. In §2.3, he discusses Quotient Singularities, mostly in the context of resolution for surfaces.

Answer (score 6):

**Curves and Singularities** by J.W. Bruce and P.J. Giblin gives a highly readable overview of basic singularity theory.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a more topological treatment of the subject, there is a two-volume **Singularities of Differentiable Maps** by Arnold, Varchenko and Gusein-Zade.

Answer (score 5):

Golubitsky and Guillemin *Stable Mappings and their singularities* is a fairly canonical reference for the Thom-Mather-Levine thread of ideas, building off of Whitney and Morse's work.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps Young person's guide to canonical singularities by Miles Reid.  The connection seems to be that at least for surfaces, canonical singularities are exactly quotient singularities by finite subgroups of SL(2,C), (rational double points).  In higher dimension the two types no longer coincide.  I am a novice, and merely repeating what I have noted from browsing.

Answer (score 3):

There is the classic **Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces** by J. W. Milnor. Try also **Topics in real and complex singularities** by A. Dimca.